# Docker-compose: no access to Wordpress files

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I just tried to host a Wordpress instance using docker on a freshly install Ubuntu machine. My problem is I am not allowed to modify the Wordpress files or create new files - I recieve `Permission denied`. I am certain that I am missing something - Can somebody explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Here are the commands I've used:

```
wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh

sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)

*restart*

sudo apt-get -y install python-pip

sudo pip install docker-compose

nano docker-compose.yml (See further down for the content of the file)

docker-compose up
```

The content of docker-compose.yml

```
wordpress:
  image: wordpress
  links:
    - wordpress_db:mysql
  ports:
    - 80:80
  volumes:
    - ./src:/var/www/html
wordpress_db:
  image: mariadb
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ****
  ports:
    - 3306:3306
phpmyadmin:
  image: corbinu/docker-phpmyadmin
  links:
    - wordpress_db:mysql
  ports:
    - 8181:80
  environment:
    MYSQL_USERNAME: root
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ****
```

Here is the contents of `ls -la` inside the `src` dir:

```
total 196
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data  4096 apr 26 16:24 .
drwxrwxr-x  3 philip   philip    4096 apr 26 16:14 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   234 apr 26 16:14 .htaccess
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   418 sep 25  2013 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 19935 mar  5 21:14 license.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  7358 dec  6 19:49 readme.html
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  5032 jan 28 04:35 wp-activate.php
drwxr-xr-x  9 www-data www-data  4096 apr 12 20:46 wp-admin
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   364 dec 19 12:20 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  1476 jan 30 22:56 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  3233 apr 26 16:24 wp-config.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  2853 apr 26 16:24 wp-config-sample.php
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data  4096 apr 26 16:33 wp-content
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  3286 maj 24  2015 wp-cron.php
drwxr-xr-x 16 www-data www-data 12288 apr 12 20:46 wp-includes
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  2380 okt 25  2013 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  3316 nov  6 00:59 wp-load.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 33837 mar  6 04:06 wp-login.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  7887 okt  6  2015 wp-mail.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 13106 feb 17 23:58 wp-settings.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 28624 jan 28 04:51 wp-signup.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  4035 nov 30  2014 wp-trackback.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  3061 okt  3  2015 xmlrpc.php
```

Comment: can you list the commands you ran and the full output (errors and all)

Comment: When you say you cannot create new files or edit files, you mean when you login to the container and cannot edit files in the terminal?